# SQL - for some attributes specific to different clients' users, how to handle schema?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

I have clients, each of whom have an app with a bunch of users.

Their user data could be pretty different, but there is also a lot of overlap. Ex: all their users have "gender" and "age" and plenty of other things, so it makes sense to have a standard user_table schema across all clients (with a column for each attribute).

But there is also user information specific to each client. Ex. one might have "relationship_status" for their users, which other clients do not have. While another has "height" for their users, which other clients do not have.

**How to I design a schema that is appropriate for both of these cases at once?**

One possibility is to somehow have a different schema for each client, but this seems like it could be unnecessary hassle. Another possibility is to put every column in the standard schema across all clients, but then the columns that are unique to a single client would just sit empty for all the other clients.

(I'm using Postgres, if that matters at all.)

Comment: You should give more information about the problem you have to solve. You said the two basic options-possibilities and you better than anyone knows what is the best to choose. Based on what you said, maybe the best is to have a table with the common information and other tables with the specific information and foreign keys...

Comment: awesome, thanks. your last suggestion is actually what somebody just suggested as a possibility, so that is a good sanity check that that idea should at least be considered.

Comment: Check out the [`hstore` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html). It is a very fast key/value store. Unless you require strong data type checking for the dynamic attributes, that's probably the best way to go.